# Javascript: Cycling through 3 images without using jQuery plugin(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

I have image thumbnails and when they are clicked, this function is called:

```
function displayMain(img, image_number)
            {
                    $("#slider-items").html('');
                    for(v = 1; v < 4; v++)
                    {
                            var j = image_number + v;
                            if(j > 3)
                            {
                                    j = j - 3;
                            }
                            $("#slider-items").append("<li><img src='/mypath/images/poi-" + img + "-" + j + "--4.jpg' width=1180 height=700 /></li>");
                    }
                    $('#slider').show();
            }
```

This works well. Now I have two navigation buttons, one for backward/previous, one for forward/next. The html classes for each are `prev_arrow` and `next_arrow`. I have an `onclick` for each like so:

```
<div class="prev_arrow" onclick="seePreviousImage()"></div>
<div class="next_arrow" onclick="seeNextImage()"></div>
```

I did an alert to make sure the `onclick`s are working and they are. Each thumbnail belongs to a map marker, and each marker has 3 thumbnails. One marker = 3 thumbnails. Each thumbnail can be clicked to display the larger image. The larger image has the prev and next arrows.

I am quite new to JS and have struggled correctly setting up sliders the past couple days using popular jQuery plugins (basic jQuery slider, uslider, etc).

If anyone could point me in the correct direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jtqC4/10/

Comment: Sent you an email, don't wanna risk posting it out here in the open.

Comment: I don't even know how to respond to that, haha

Comment: Can you take the relevant parts (only the slider and code for it) and put it into a jsFiddle for us? It'd be much easier for us to work with

Comment: Yeah sure I can, but the images aren't defined in the html (it's just blank `src==""`.

Comment: So add some random images or use PlaceHoldIt

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtqC4/9/ hopefully that helps somewhat. Forgive the noobness.

Comment: At the moment you only have the alert, you're not calling the function at all. Do you know how to call the function?

Comment: The html onclicks are calling the functions, yes I realize those two functions only have alerts. I'm just confused on how to go about the logic to get the prev/next functions working properly.

Comment: Well, if you know they all have the set width then you can use `position:absolute` and move right or left that amount based on that number. Otherwise you have to calculate the width of the next element in the direction of the click and move that amount instead. Perhaps `elem.clientWidth` may help you

Comment: Cool cool. I'll look into it and let you know :) Thanks for helping out.